# Laravel - controller executed before everything else

Tags: php, frameworks, laravel

I'm using Laravel web framework for a PHP project. I have a question about this framework, the documentation (which is poor), and the community from IRC doesn't helped me.

I want to create a controller which will be executed before any other controller. I want in this controller to pass some variables to view. How is this possible?

Thank you.

Comment: Usually only one controller is executed per request. It sounds like you could make use of [view composers](http://four.laravel.com/docs/responses#view-composers) or using `View::share` in conjunction with [route filters](http://four.laravel.com/docs/routing#route-filters). And there was no need to start your question off with those remarks. Be grateful for help, it's not always a given. I'm on IRC now and there are plenty of others around too. Jump back on.

Answer (score 2):

You can do such thing in the `before` filter, in `routes.php` (, for Laravel 4 its `filters.php`).

Or if you need to do it in controller then create a BaseController which should extend `Controller`, in Laravel 3 you should have this already, `base.php`. And all your controllers should extend this BaseController, in its `__construct` or in `before` filter do this for ease:

```
View::share('key', 'value');
```

And use it as `$key` in your views.

Note, `View::share` can be problematic sometimes.